# How to organize JavaScript in Yii project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I write project using Yii.I would like to receive advice on how to organize my JavaScript.I thought about several options:

1. Put all code in one file (app.js), create for each feature moduls and attach it to each page of project.But problem is that not all feature required in all pages and so in this case I have to load useless code and it is difficult to navigate among hundreds of lines.(I know that I can write in separate files and then "compile" all in one, but it does not solve problem of excess code)
2. Create for each feature separate file and manage it loading through Yii(attach only necessary files to page). But some feature require only couple lines of code and it seems irrational to create file for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mixing of Asset and layout

In  a proper layout   stored inside your_app\views\layouts\your_asset_filename.php
you could  register a specific asset

```
  use your_app\assets\YourAsset;

  //use common\models\UserParam;
  //use common\models\LandScope;

  /* @var $this \yii\web\View */
  /* @var $content string */

  YourAssest::register($this);

  ?>
```

In your_app\asset you could configure the js files you needs

```
class YourAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        ........
    ];
    public $js = [
        'your_js1.js',
        'your_js2.js',
        ....
    ];
    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

and last your controller/action  you can set the layout you need for each render

```
public function actionMyAction()
{
   $this->layout = 'your_asset_filename';

   ... 
   return $this->render('your_view',[ ....]);

}
```